# scanning the area with rotating turtlebot 2

Tags: ros, robotics

I'm working on a project with ROS using gzebo simulator and turtlebot 2.
I'm trying to make my robot navigate himself into a clear path.
my robot moves only forward, and my idea was to rotate it 360 degrees and get readings from his laser scan, and then get back to the angle that had a reading
that represents a clear path.

I'm having trouble thinking about a right implementation though and would like to get some reviews about my idea and any suggestions that could help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem exactly?

- detecting the clear path after the rotation?
- Rotating to it and driving into it?
- Something else?

Is there a reason why you can not use the global & local planner of ROS and simple calculate a goal for them after the rotation?

Or you mean your robot can only drive straight and rotate in place? No driving curves?

Than take the global plan and check for each cell after the start, if it is reachable in  a straight line without hitting an obstacle. If not, drive to the previous reachable cell rotate there and start anew.